# Autocompletion not working for "@" in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, autocomplete, xcode6

I have an Objective-C project in Xcode 6. In Xcode 5, when I type the "@" character, it autocompletes for you, but it doesn't do that in Xcode 6. I couldn't find an option to enable this in settings/preferences, does anyone happen to know how to get this feature back? For objects, classes and constants etc, autocompletion works.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple changed an autocomplete behavior and now you should hit **ESC** right after you pressed **@** symbol.

Do not forget to enable this "feature" in **settings** menu:

**Xcode preferences > Text editing > Use Escape key to show completion suggestions**